# How to print tree structure with java？

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I have a question, if the provided data list looks like this: (There are three columns, the first column is ‘id’, the second column is ‘parent_id’, and the third column is ‘name’)

id parent_id name 1 0 AA 2 1 BB 3 1 CC 4 3 DD 5 3 EE 6 2 FF 7 2 GG 8 4 HH 9 5 II 10 0 JJ 11 10 KK 12 10 LL

Then how to print on the console in an indented tree structure, indented by spaces. How to do? I tried several versions, but it still doesn't work. How can this be done? How to write to meet this condition。

Specifically, I need to represent the following:
The effect of the tree structure is like this, there are bb and cc under aa, dd and ee under cc, and ff and gg under bb.

I wrote this code: (The tree structure has been defined)

```
public class Tree{
    static class Node{
        int id;
        int parentId;
        String name;
        public Node(int id,int parentId,String name){
            this.id=id;
            this.name=name;
            this.parentId=parentId;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Node>nodeList = Arrays.asList(
                new Node(1,0,"aa"),
                new Node(2,1,"bb"),
                new Node(3,1,"cc"),
                new Node(4,3,"dd"),
                new Node(5,3,"ee"),
                new Node(6,2,"ff"),
                new Node(7,2,"gg"),
                new Node(8,4,"hh"),
                new Node(9,5,"ii"),
                new Node(10,0,"jj"),
                new Node(11,10,"kk"),
                new Node(12,10,"ll"));
        print(nodeList);
    }

    public static void print(List<Node>nodeList) {
        //todo

    }
}
```

Comment: please share the `print` function that you tried but didn't work. let us know what didn't work

Comment: Yes, I just don’t know how to write this print, what should be the idea

Comment: Why did you post this question again? (cf [first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469218/how-to-print-out-an-indented-tree-structure-using-java)). You should delete this question and edit the other according to the comments you received.

Comment: I have modified the question according to the prompt